# TWIG form template: call variable in attr

Tags: twig, symfony4, attr

In a twig form template in Symfony 4 app I need to have an attribute with a variable.

Exemple:

```
{{ form_widget(myform.field, {'attr': {'class': 'bidding-slider','data-slider-value': '800'}}) }}
```

I need to put a variable in 'data-slider-value' instead of a manual value.

I tried :

```
{{ form_widget(myform.field, {'attr': {'class': 'bidding-slider','data-slider-value': '{{ variable }}'}}) }}
```

but it do not work...

{{ variable }} alone return well the value I need to put in 'data-slider-value'.

Second tried:

I have Extended  form class 'TextType' method buildView.
To do that I added this file : src/Form/Extension/TextTypeExtension.php

```
// src/Form/Extension/TextTypeExtension.php
namespace App\Form\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;

    class TextTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    /**
     * Return the class of the type being extended.
     */
    public static function getExtendedTypes(): iterable
    {
        // return FormType::class to modify (nearly) every field in the system
        return [TextType::class];
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
    $tjm = $form->get('dailyrate')->getData();
    $view->vars['attr']['data-slider-value'] = $tjm;
    }
}
```

But now I am not sure of the way to use that in my form template...

Thank you very much for helping me.

Alex

Answer (score 0):

Extend your form's class method `buildView`:

```
public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    $view->vars['attr']['data-slider-value'] = ...// 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this advice :) I update my initial post with what I have done